# Travis build failing because of "Error: Cannot find module"

Tags: javascript, package, travis-ci

I have a strange issue:
When I run travis on my build, it fails.

The issue is following:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'
```

The funny thing is, that it's clearly installed and available in the package.json file:

[image]

When I move the package from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`, it works, but then another package has the same issue.

The installation command for html-webpack-plugin is:

```
$ npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

So it should be in the `devDependencies` and not `dependencies`

Anybody an idea, why this is happening?

Comment: Check the Δversion between `npm`/`node` on Travis and your machine. Try to equalise them. See if the problem persists.

Comment: Please this is something that has been bugging me a while. Some help